# Does a Sorcery with Support trigger Zada, Hedron Grinder's ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If a sorcery (like [Press into Service](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Press%20into%20Service) for example) has the support ability, would casting it and supporting only [Zada, Hedron Grinder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Zada%2C%20Hedron%20Grinder) activate his ability? Is the "targets only Zada" requirement met by the support? Or would the card have to specifically say "target creature"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support has [this definition](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Support):

> “Support N” on a permanent means “Put a +1/+1 counter on each of up to N other target creatures.” “Support N” on an instant or sorcery spell means **“Put a +1/+1 counter on each of up to N target creatures.”**

So, "Support 2" on Press into Service is the same as if the card actually had "Put a +1/+1 counter on each of up to 2 target creatures" printed on it. This means that yes, if you cast a spell with Support N, and the only target is Zada, Hedron Grinder, then the ability triggers and the spell is copied.

However, note that this is impossible with [Nissa's Judgement](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=407649) (and Press into Service if you want to actually take control of an opponent's creature), because they require you to choose another target besides the ones you support.

Comment: Press Into Service doesn't say "target creature you don't control", so you could support onto Zada and target Zada with the second part, which would trigger it's ability.

Comment: That's true. I clarified that point.

Comment: Very interesting. So Press into Service on Zada is "Put a +1/+1 counter, untap, and give haste to team"?